# sync elasticsearch and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

Hi I am trying to transport data from mongodb to elasticsearch. I have done it by following this [tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/sy1qcw/setting-up-elasticsearch-with-mongodb). It is working for elasticsearch version 1.X. But when I tried to do it with version 5.X. plug-ins can't be installed. Can someone help me to figure out a way to do it with version 5.X.

These are the two plugins.

```
$ES_HOME/bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/1.6.0

plugin --install com.github.richardwilly98.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/2.0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

In elastic 5.x+ the installation commands are different. The mapper attachment library you're trying to install has an example [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments)

```
bin/plugin install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/3.1.2
```

[The other library does not mention support of Elastic > 2.x](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb), and its last commit was well before 5.x existed.

If you need to use that exact library, I don't believe you will be able to use anything > 2.x

Comment: What is the library I can use instead of that library then?

Comment: @M.Ramzan Did you get your question sorted out?

Comment: No, I am trying the mongo-connector and I followed every steps. It didn't showed any errors. But the data didn't get inserted.